# Why is the 2nd while-do loop not running in my function

Tags: c, cs50, control-flow

I am working on CS50 and learning C. I am getting myself confused about utilizing while-do loops to ensure that the user puts in an integer. I am trying to create a function that prompts for your age and then your friend's age. However, after the first while-do loop returns false, shouldn't it move to the 2nd while-do loop in my `get_ages()` function? I would love some help on this.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int get_ages();


int main(void)
{
    printf("%i\n", get_ages());
}

//Get your age function
int get_ages(int your_age, int friend_age)
{
    do
    {
        your_age = get_int("What is your age: ");
        return your_age;
    }
    while (your_age < 1);

    do
    {
        friend_age = get_int("What is your friends age: ");
        return friend_age;
    }
    while (friend_age < 1);
}
```

Comment: `return` does not just exit a loop, it exits the whole function. Use `break` if you want to exit from the loop and continue the function. But of course the `break` should be inside a conditional otherwise the loop will always run just once.

Comment: @kaylum Interesting. Would I put break; under the return your_age line? That didnt seem to work, kind of unsure where I should put that!

Comment: How do you expect `get_ages()` to return both values?

Comment: @MichaelM. Ah! So in otherwords these might need to be in separate functions or use something other than a while-do loop?

Comment: You can either learn about pointers and pass pointers into the function so that both ages can be stored. Or yes, change the function to get and return just one age and then call it twice.

Comment: @techladdie123 Not necessarily. You can have the function update the value of some other variable. See my answer below.

Comment: Okay... If it worked, the function could prompt for 2 ages... Then what? What is the expected output of this program? The youngest? The oldest? The difference in ages? What?

Comment: You can't program by trial & error, typing random stuff while guessing how the language might work. Not only does the return not make any sense, neither does the whole function `int get_ages(int your_age, int friend_age)`. You need to actually study how functions, function parameter passing and function return values work.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration `int get_ages();` and your definition of the function `int get_ages(int your_age, int friend_age)` do not match.  In `main()` you call `get_ages()` without arguments.  If you want to pass data to caller via an argument (sometimes referred to as an out parameter) then you need to pass in the address of said variables:

```
int your_age;
int friend_age;
get_ages(&your_age, &friend_age);
```

The declaration would then be `void get_ages(int *your_age, int &friend_age)` you in the function you would set the value like this `*your_age = get_int(...)` etc.

`return` *terminates* a function and pass the optional value to caller.  This means you will only ever execute a single return statement within a function.

In c, you can only return 1 value, so you need to return a struct or array if you have multiple things you want to return.

I suggest you change the function to just return a single value, pass in a prompt, then call the function twice:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_age(const char *prompt) {
    int age;
    do {
        age = get_int(prompt);
    } while (age < 1);
    return age;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%i\n", get_age("What is your age? "));
    printf("%i\n", get_age("What is your friend's age? "));
}
```